# Funnel non-activated users to a single page and restricting access

Tags: authentication, yii

So, given that I have user table with a field of "is_confirmed", I want funnel anyone with an "is_confirmed" that is equal to 0 to a single url using the redirect...

Is there a way to do this check so that it only needs to be implemented once?  I guess a good example would be the default user functionality of how any page that requires a logged-in user forces the user to the login page...

Comment: Welcome to SO! When asking a question make sure you give as much information as possible. Post some of your code, explain what you have tried and what specific areas you need help in. We are here to help, not do your work for you.

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199406/yii-catch-all-incoming-requests

Comment: Mr. Jordan Carroll,  I apologize if I have offended you somehow with my request for code that someone may have already implemented.  It just seemed like a time-saver for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tried this specifically myself, but based on Yii's documentation one would probably [redirect the user inside the login action](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#login-and-logout) based on the value. If the user is confirmed, call the CWebUser::login(..) method to store the identity in persistent storage and use the returnUrl redirect, otherwise the user is not confirmed so skip that part and just render the *in limbo* page.

Inside your SiteController::actionLogin() you'll probably do something like this (additionally the UserIdentity component should have a method for returning the value of the confirmation field)-

```
$identity = new UserIdentity();
if($identity->authenticate()) {
  if($identity->isConfirmed() == 1) {
    Yii::app()->user->login($identity);
    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
  } else {
    $this->render('not_yet_confirmed_view');
  }
} else {
  throw new CHttpException(500,'Internal Server Error. Could not authenticate.');
}
```

Edit- Removed the accidental extra CWebUser::login() and clarified that the UserIdentity component will require just a bit of additional smarts.

Comment: Actually this might work if I load the user model after authenticating the first time, then checking to see if the is_confirmed == 1.  I realize now that instead of redirecting, I could use a render and include the loaded user model which will contain information that I could use to generate a new confirmation code should I ultimately require it.  Cheers to this answer -- I'll implement your suggestion and my idea and see what comes up.  I'm pretty sure that you didn't mean to put the first Yii::app()->user->login($identity), but if you did.. why?

Comment: Yes, that was an extraneous CWebUser::login() (fixed!). And yes, you'll have to load the user model to grab that confirmed parameter. I modified the example to clarify that in this case the UserIdentity component kept track of the user model internally but it could be done in a variety of ways.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts buddy, I got this done the way I needed to with your help.  MUCH appreciated!!